# CGContextDrawPath won't fill

Tags: swift, core-graphics

I'm trying to fill some triangles I have drawn, however they aren't filling. Below is the code which draws in the context, and as you can see in the picture the path strokes fine.

```
func draw(context:CGContextRef) {
    CGContextBeginPath(context)
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.peak.x, self.peak.y)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.left.x,self.left.y)
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.left.x, self.left.y)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.right.x,self.right.y)
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.right.x, self.right.y)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.peak.x,self.peak.y)
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,UIColor.blackColor().CGColor)
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context,UIColor.redColor().CGColor)
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke)
}
```

I call that function twice and the output is this.

[image]

I'm reading the Quartz2D programming guide but can't see why this wouldn't fill. This is just happening in a playground in a class that inherits from UIView, nothing fancy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each call to `CGContextMoveToPoint()` starts a new subpath,
which is then filled as if you had closed it (and there is nothing
to see if you fill a single line segment). To stroke and fill
a triangle, use:

```
CGContextBeginPath(context)

CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.peak.x, self.peak.y)
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.left.x,self.left.y)
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.right.x,self.right.y)
CGContextClosePath(context)

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,UIColor.blackColor().CGColor)
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context,UIColor.redColor().CGColor)
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke)
```

Comment: ah thank you, that makes sense. how does it figure out to close the triangle? or does CGContextAddLineToPoint also move the current point?

Comment: @chris: Yes, CGContextAddLineToPoint() appends a line segment from the current point to the given point and makes the new point the current point. CGContextClosePath() appends a line segment from the current point to the initial point of the subpath.